# Hosting rebooted server, can not connect from laptop, can from elsewhere

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, connection

I chatted with support on an issue yesterday. As part of the resolution the agent decided to reboot the server (...without permission). Since then I have not been able to access either the live site or the WHM/cPanel site. However, I can access both sites from my phone's mobile data.

I know both sites were fine before the chat, as I was doing work on them. And to access the chat I had to log in to the WHM.

Trying to visit those pages returns a timeout error (from any browser). This is the result of `ping`:

```
Pinging 108.175.155.92 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 108.175.155.92:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

I'm in a rut, since I can not connect to the site from my development machine. Any ideas what may have caused this or what I can do to regain connection?

Comment: Ping seems to be working but CPanel shows a configuration error.

Answer (score 0):

Later speaking with another agent from the hosting company, my IP had been blacklisted from too many SSH failed log in attempts. . . which was the original reason I wrote in to support! There was no programming error. Just an uninformed client and an non-knowledgeable agent.